# F3 - Descargar CSV generado con PHP en AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo una aplicación web que genera un CSV a partir de una consulta a una BD, el cual quiero descargar, estoy llamando a la ruta que genera el archivo mediante una petición Ajax, pero no tengo idea de como hacer la descarga de dicho archivo.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: direccion() + 'descargas/exportar',
    dataType: '//Que tipo deberia poner¿?'
}).done(function () {
    //Aqui se debería guardar el archivo
}).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
    alert('Error ' + xhr.status + '. ' + error + ': ' + xhr.responseText);
});
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama al AJAX? Si es al pulsar en un botón/enlace, ¿por qué no enlazar directamente la URL?

Comment: Efectivamente el AJAX se llama cuando se pulsa un botón. No enlazo directamente la URL del archivo puesto que este lo genero en tiempo de ejecución, por lo que (según sé) no está en el sistema de archivos del servidor.

Comment: Jajaja... Olvídenlo... Estaba llamando mal al controlador que hace la descarga del archivo.  Y gracias a la respuesta de Alvaro, sólo llamé a la URL del controlador `window.open(direccion() + 'descargas/exportar');`